# Minecraft spawneggs CanPlaceOn

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to give myself a wolf spawn egg named Bradley (or a different name) that can be placed on grass.

I have tried:

`/give @p minecraft:spawn_egg 1 0 {Entitytag:{id:"Wolf",CustomName:"Bradley"CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:grass"]}}`

Can someone please help me?

Comment: I believe the id for the wolf egg is minecraft:spawn_egg:95

Answer (score 1):

The correct command for 1.12 is:

```
/give @p spawn_egg 1 0 {EntityTag:{id:"minecraft:wolf",CustomName:"Bradley"},CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:grass"]}
```

Here is a command with the proper hideflag to hide the CanPlaceOn data:

```
/give @p spawn_egg 1 0 {EntityTag:{id:"minecraft:wolf",CustomName:"Bradley"},CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:grass"],HideFlags:16}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, `CanPlaceOn` only works for blocks.

Comment: In my testing, command works properly.  In adventure mode, eggs spawn if used only on grass block.

Comment: can you also hide it's name?

Comment: In my original command you didn't see it's name but when you placed it it showed it's name

Comment: I just edited the answer to fix that.