# How to get a certain spawn egg that can be placed on a specific block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been thinking hard and tried multiple times but none of them have worked. I want a **specific** (let's say creeper) **spawn egg** and I want it to be able to be **placeable** on a block **in adventure mode** and have it be **named**. Please, someone help!

Here is the method I've tried that don't work:

```
/give @p minecraft:spawn_egg 1 0 {EntityTag:{id:"minecraft:creeper",CustomName:"NAME",CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:grass","minecraft:dirt"]}}
```

All it does is give me a spawn creeper with no custom name and can't be placed on anything. No one has put a "How to" video or thread on YouTube or Google or anything. Please help.

Comment: What have you found in your research?  What have you tried?  There are two unrelated questions in your question which is generally discouraged.  [Here is a question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/313113/186522) that could be considered duplicate.  The answer should answer your first question.

Comment: Please only ask one question per question. And in general, do research. We're not your code producing machine, we're here to help for specific problems.

Comment: You said you have tried multiple methods but they all failed.  List those attempts.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close.  CanPlaceOn data is not a part of the EntityTag.

Here is the structure needed:

```
/give @p spawn_egg 1 0 {EntityTag:{id:"...",CustomName:"..."},CanPlaceOn:["..."]}
```

Here is a structure which specifies a lot of NBT data that might be helpful:

```
/give @p spawn_egg 1 0 {display:{Name:"..."},EntityTag:{id:"...",CustomName:"..."},CanPlaceOn:["..."],HideFlags:16}
```

The `...` represents data to be filled in.  From left to right, the display name will contain the desired name of the egg, the id will contain the [entity ID](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_data_values#Entity_IDs) the egg will spawn, the CustomName will contain the name of the entity the egg spawns, the CanPlaceOn will contain the [block ID(s)](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_data_values#Block_IDs) of the block(s) the egg can be used on, and [HideFlags](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Command_NBT_tags#Items) hides the CanPlaceOn data.  Tags can simply be omitted if they are not desired.  A few example commands:

```
/give @p spawn_egg 1 0 {EntityTag:{id:"minecraft:creeper",CustomName:"Freddy Creeper"},CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:grass"]}

/give @p spawn_egg 1 0 {display:{Name:"Custom Egg"},EntityTag:{id:"minecraft:pig",CustomName:"Sir Oinks A Lot"},CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:dirt"]}

/give @p spawn_egg 1 0 {display:{Name:"Humpty Dumpty"},EntityTag:{id:"minecraft:chicken",CustomName:"Humpty Dumpty's Mom"},CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:grass","minecraft:stone"],HideFlags:16}
```

Here is a complicated example to show what can be spawned with an egg:

```
/give @p spawn_egg 1 0 {display:{Name:"Warrior Egg"},EntityTag:{id:"minecraft:zombie",CustomName:"War Monster",HandItems:[{Count:1b,id:"minecraft:diamond_sword"},{Count:1b,id:"minecraft:shield"}],ArmorItems:[{Count:1b,id:"minecraft:diamond_boots"},{Count:1b,id:"minecraft:diamond_leggings"},{Count:1b,id:"minecraft:diamond_chestplate"},{Count:1b,id:"minecraft:diamond_helmet"}],HandDropChances:[1.0f,1.0f],ArmorDropChances:[1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f]},CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:grass","minecraft:stone"],HideFlags:16}
```